# How do I validate v-forms within a v-data-table on page load?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have built the below data entry form using a `v-data-table` with each column containing a `v-form` and `v-text-field` so that the values can be updated directly within the form. I would like to validate each of the fields on load of the page to indicate any places where previously entered data is incorrect. I am having trouble getting all of the fields to validate on load. I have tried adding a `ref` for each form column and calling the `validate()` function in the `mounted()` function, but that only validates the first row on page load. I've also tried several variations on validating the form within the form load event (e.g. `v-form @load="this.validate()"`). How can I modify my code to validate the entire data table on load of the page?

## Form

[image: Form layout]

## Code

### Template

```
<v-card max-width="95%">
    <v-card-title>Collateral</v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
      :items="this.$store.state.CurrentInstrumentDetails.collateral"
      :headers="headers"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.disbursable="{ item }">
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-spacer />
            <v-col cols="5">
              <v-form ref="disbursable_form">
              <v-text-field
                type="text"
                class="justify-center"
                dense
                :value="item.disbursable"
                :rules="calculatedFieldValidations"
                @change="
                  valueChanged(
                    item.collateral_balance_id,
                    'disbursable',
                    $event
                  )
                "
              ></v-text-field>
              </v-form>
            </v-col>
            <v-spacer />
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.pending_transfer="{ item }">
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-spacer />
            <v-col cols="5">
              <v-form ref="pending_transfer_form">
              <v-text-field
                type="text"
                class="justify-center"
                dense
                :value="item.pending_transfer"
                :rules="calculatedFieldValidations"
                @change="
                  valueChanged(
                    item.collateral_balance_id,
                    'pending_transfer',
                    $event
                  )
                "
              ></v-text-field>
              </v-form>
            </v-col>
            <v-spacer />
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
</v-card>
```

### Typescript

```
mounted() {
    (this.$refs.disbursable_form as any).validate();
    (this.$refs.pending_transfer_form as any).validate();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I ended up solving it. I moved the `<v-form>` outside of the `<v-data-table>` and added a two-second delay to calling the `validate()` function.

## Code

### Template

```
<v-card max-width="95%">
    <v-card-title>Collateral</v-card-title>
    <v-form ref="collateral_form">
        <v-data-table
          :items="this.$store.state.CurrentInstrumentDetails.collateral"
          :headers="headers"
        >
          .
          .
          .
        </v-data-table>
    </v-form>
</v-card>
```

### Typescript

```
mounted() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    (this.$refs.collateral_form as any).validate();
  }, 2000); 
}
```